# What happens with the voltage and amperage when we have multiple batteries in either series or parallel?

Tags: voltage, parallel, amperage, series

Let's assume that I have 4 pieces of 9v batteries and some simple load like an LED. If it helps, you can assume there is no load at all.

**Question 1** - What voltage and amperage can I expect on the output when I have a simple series circuit?

```
    plus   minus   plus   minus   plus   minus   plus   minus
+---(9v-battery)---(9v-battery)---(9v-battery)---(9v-battery)---+
|                                                               |
+----------------------(load)---------------(V?)-----(Amp?)-----+
```

**Question 2** - What voltage and amperage can I expect on the output when I have a parallel circuit?

```
         plus   minus
+--------(9v-battery)--------+
|                            |
|        plus   minus        |
+--------(9v-battery)--------+
|                            |
|        plus   minus        |
+--------(9v-battery)--------+
|                            |
|        plus   minus        |
+--------(9v-battery)--------+
|                            |
|                            |
+---(load)---(V?)---(Amp?)---+
```

I am quite inexperienced in this area and even though I know the difference between series and parallel circuits, I don't know what to expect when I have **multiple** battery sources. I believe that in one of these cases I should expect the batteries to last longer and in the other case I should expect the voltage (and therefore perhaps the amperage as well) to increase.

Could you please explain to me what happens with the voltage, the amperage and the overall battery life in each case? Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I found out that my Google search regarding this topic has been slightly incorrect and that's why I didn't get the answers I was looking for. I updated my Google search with better terms and I found these articles which were very helpful:

[Connecting Batteries in Series or Parallel](http://www.zbattery.com/Connecting-Batteries-in-Series-or-Parallel)

[Battery Bank Tutorial - Series and Parallel](https://www.batterystuff.com/kb/articles/battery-articles/battery-bank-tutorial.html)

Thank you all for your answers and comments on this issue! I promise the next time to do better research before posting questions here.

Comment: The load is not irrelevant. It is half of the equation. An LED is not a simple load. It is non-linear. You will get the best tutorial by searching for a tutorial, not by asking questions based on false assumptions. This is a site for asking questions, not for getting personalized tutorials.

Comment: @Charles - I am sorry if I have offended you with my lack of knowledge in this particular area! I didn't know that I need tutorial because I thought my question is a simple one. Besides, there are quite a lot available resources for resistors in series and parallel but I didn't find a suitable explanation which involves electrical sources in series and parallel. That's why I decided to ask my question here.

Comment: I am not offended, and you have a couple of answers. The question is simple, but it reveals an underlying need to study the basic principles more carefully.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment and close vote. I removed the erroneous assumptions from the question. Others have voted to close and/or down voted the question.

Comment: @IvanDavidov: The question may seem very simple, but electrical engineering tends to be non-trivial in almost everything. it can be frustrating ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the batteries in series, the total voltage is the sum of the individual battery voltages (a 9 volt battery is made up of six 1.5 volt cells in series).  The current capacity is the same as for one battery, as all of the current has to flow through all the batteries

With the batteries in parallel, the voltage is the same as for a single battery, but the current capacity will be four times that of a single battery as each battery is supplying part of the total current.

Comment: So, am I right to assume that since the parallel circuit draws more current, then my LED (the load) will be brighter?

And in the series circuit - does this mean that my LED brightness will stay the same and my batteries will last 4 times longer?

Comment: You've got it reversed. The only thing (in this case) that will make the LED draw more current and be brighter is voltage. Batteries in series=higher voltage=brighter LED (more current, shorter battery life). Batteries in parallel=same voltage=same LED brightness (more current capacity from batteries, longer battery life).

Comment: The parallel battery circuit can provide more current than the series batteries - but your load determines how much current is actual drawn from the batteries. The brightness of an LED depends on the current through the LED.  You have to control this current by adding a current-limiting resistor or constant currrent source in series with the LED.

Answer (score 1):

Q1... Voltage sources in series add. Current capacity would be the same but voltage would be 4x9 or 36 volts. Battery life would depend on load.

Q2... Voltage sources in parallel would be 9V. Current capacity would be 4x? (whatever the current capacity of the voltage source(s) is). Battery life would depend on load.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the _battery life would depend on load_ thing? Assuming the load is simple one (e.g. LED) then in which case I should expect longer overall battery life?

Comment: If the power (IE) requirements of the load is the same in each instance then battery life would be pretty much the same.It's not so simple to compare loads- an LED with a series resistor that would work fine at 9V would need a higher value resistor at 36 volts. More power would be lost in the resistor, but current through the LED would be the same in both cases.